# How to loop through numbers in dplyr

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, using

I have written a query that gives the number of false positives based on a percentage (A). I want to work out how many false positives different percentages produce.

I know I can change A each time but want to automate the process using a minimum A, maximum A and every 10 numbers in between (10, 20 ..., 100)

Example code

```
df <- tibble("id" = 1:100, "Perc_change" = rnorm(100, mean = 15, sd = 5), "v1" = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 4))

A <- 10

df %>% 
  mutate(x1 = if_else(Perc_change > A, 1, 0),
         x2 = if_else((Perc_change > A) & (v1 > 0 )), 1, 0)) %>% 
  select(x1,x2) %>% 
  summarise(perc = A,
            true = sum(x1 ==1),
            false = sum(x1 == 1 & x2 == 0),
            true_perc = true/(true+false)*100)
```

I would like a table that shows the value of A, true, false, true_perc for different values of A.

This is the current output of my table

```
A   true  false  true_perc
10  120    80      60
```

I would like for the table to be like this:

```
A   true    false    true_perc
10  19721    33767      37
20  18541    29720      38
...
100 10203    11431      47
```

Comment: Please include an input example instead of what you are getting as output (for others to test the code)

Comment: If you are doing this step once in a while, store the output to a file, and write with append = TRUE to that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to loop, we can use `map` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(seq(10, 100, by = 10), ~ 
      df %>% 
         transmute(x1 = as.integer(Perc_change  > .x),
                   x2 = as.integer(x1 & (v1 > 0)) ) %>% 
         summarise(perc = .x, 
                   true = sum(x1), 
                   false = sum(x1 & !x2 ), 
                   true_perc = true/(true + false) * 100))
```